# changed password, can't push to private repository

Tags: git, github

I just changed my GitHub password.

I tried `git push` to a **private** repository I was working on.

Got the error

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/*/*/'
```

I did some searching and ended up running these commands to try to fix:

```
$ git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
$ git push
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/*/*/' not found
$ git config --global --unset user.password
$ git push
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/*/*/' not found
$ vim ~/.gitconfig
```

> I delete the `[credential]` section

```
$ git push
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/*/*/' not found
```

I am never getting prompted for my username/password.

How can I "log in" or gain push rights to my remote private GitHub repository again?